# Does std::endl << std::flush have a purpose?

Tags: c++, flush, endl

`std::flush` right after a `std::endl` is used all over the legacy code I am looking at. When I first saw this, my thought was it is redundant from looking at the description of `std::endl` and `std::flush` at:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush

Here is an example of what I am seeing in the legacy source code:

```
std::cout << "Generic Notification" << std::endl << std::flush;
```

But, as many **senior** software developers have seen this code throughout the years, I am wondering if there is some detail I am missing. Is there any purpose to having a `std::flush` after a `std::endl`?

Comment: if it wasnt `std::cout` but some other stream there might be a reason...

Comment: @user463035818 And what would that be? `std::endl` is defined as "end line & flush."

Comment: @Angew if I write my own stream that has `operator<<` overloads for `std::endl` and `std::flush` i can make them work any way I want, no?

Comment: @user463035818 Oh, you meant if it was not a standard stream at all. Yes, then indeed it could make sense (if the stream implementor's logic was twisted enough). I interpreted your comment as comparing `std::cout` to other `std` streams (e.g. a `std::ofstream` instance).

Comment: @Angew I just considered the chance that OP replaced whatever stream it was in the original code with `std::cout` for the sake of a mcve. Of course even for a custom streamlike object the `flush` should not have any use in that place

Comment: @user463035818 For the mcve I just used std out, but also there are calls to std error in the legacy code that use this std::endl << std::flush.

Comment: my first comment more precise: There might be a reason for the `flush` if it wasnt a standard stream, though it still wouldnt be a good reason, because a stream that does not flush on `endl` can be considered broken

Comment: maybe just noone ever had the cochones to tell the seniors that this makes no sense ;)

Comment: @user463035818  haha, after getting the feedback from SO, now I will

Comment: @user463035818: Maybe someone just did `sed -ri 's/std::cout (<< .*);$/std::cout \1 << std::flush;/'` on the source at some point.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's no purpose for it.

If I had to speculate on why your legacy code contains these lines, there are a few possibilities, starting with (what I consider to be) the most probable scenarios:

- Someone added the explicit call to `std::flush` mistakenly, and the senior developers didn't consider it a problem needing fixing
- The code originates from a time before the C++ standard was widely adopted, and in that time, the local compiler's implementation of `std::endl` did not trigger a flush, which meant that your senior developers were (correctly) understanding that it was necessary
- An older version of the C++ standard might not have required `std::endl` to trigger a flush
- Your senior developers are mistaken about the behavior of `std::endl`.
- Your execution environment is a strange behemoth that actually requires output to be flushed twice before the desired result can be expected.

Comment: Silly things like this can also appear when text search & replace is performed on source code, such as: replace `<< '\n'`with `<< std::endl`

Comment: Good answer, but "an older version of the C++ standard…" – no, C++98 was the first standard, and it did require a `flush`. At best, some early version of the standard library may have behaved differently, though I doubt it. BTW, I can think of a reason why they would use `endl` instead of `'\n’` despite not realizing it flushes, which is a system that does not have LF line terminator (most likely Windows). Of course this is not necessary on `cout`/`cerr`, nor a text mode `ofstream`, and then again `endl` doesn't even help for a binary `ofstream`, but that may have been the mistaken reasoning.

Comment: I particularly like the last scenario.

Answer (score 8):

I'll add to the other valid answers that, very often, there isn't a good purpose for *neither* `std::flush` nor `std::endl`.

Basically, `std::endl` = start a new line + flush the stream. A lot of people, though, tend to end their lines with `std::endl` because it "sounds right" - end the line. But we actually rarely need to flush the output stream. Sometimes we do (e.g. when we're expecting a user's reply to the string, or it's important to monitor our output with minimal delay) - but that's the exception, not the rule.

So, it might take a bit of getting used to, but we should really default to simply:

```
std::cout << bunch_of_stuff << '\n';
```

and that's that!

Comment: Yes!  Use `std::cerr` if you need output to be flushed to a terminal.

Comment: When testing / debugging it's handy that your output is flushed.

Answer (score 5):

In a standards-compliant environment, `std::flush` serves no useful purpose in this code.

Whoever wrote this either didn't fully understand the semantics of `std::endl`, or were working around some limitation of their compiler or execution environment.